# Calculating sum of a values after join

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `itemId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemCategoryId` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerId` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `orders_items` (
  `orderItemId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orderId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `itemId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderItemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_items_quantity` (
  `orderItemId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `size` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`orderItemId`,`size`,`quantity`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `items` (`itemId`, `itemCategoryId`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Jeans Model A (Category Jeans)'),
    (2, 1, 'Jeans Model B (Category Jeans)'),
    (3, 2, 'T-Shirt Model A (Category T-Shirt)');

INSERT INTO `orders` (`orderId`, `customerId`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1);

INSERT INTO `orders_items` (`orderItemId`, `orderId`, `itemId`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 1),
    (4, 2, 2),
    (5, 3, 1),
    (6, 3, 3);

INSERT INTO `order_items_quantity` (`orderItemId`, `size`, `quantity`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 5),
    (3, 1, 1),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 1, 1),
    (4, 2, 1),
    (5, 1, 4),
    (6, 1, 3);
```

---

I can't merge 'order_items' with 'order_items_quantity' because I have other fields in the first table about the items regardless the size (es. their prices in that moment) that would be wasted disk space if I repeat them in only one table.

I need a query to get the sum of all the ordered quantities of any item of a certain category by each customer regerdless of the size. Something like:

```
customerId itemCategoryId total_quantity_ordered
1          1              17
2.         1              5
2.         2.             3
```

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT total_quantities.total_quantity_ordered, orders.customerId, items.itemCategoryId FROM orders 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT orders_items.orderId, SUM(order_items_quantity.quantity) AS total_quantity_ordered 
    FROM orders_items 
    JOIN order_items_quantity ON order_items_quantity.orderItemId=orders_items.orderItemId 
    GROUP BY orders_items.orderId
) AS total_quantities ON total_quantities.orderId=orders.orderId 
JOIN orders_items ON orders_items.orderId=orders.orderId
JOIN items ON items.itemId=orders_items.itemId
GROUP BY orders.customerId, items.itemCategoryId
```

but it selects only the first order of every customer containing that categoryId. Any help is appreciated.

SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnxomXfobBN25nTJvASVdL/0

Comment: update your question add alos a proper data sample  (not only schema and  expected  result)

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge I just updated the answer, I hope I did it good

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS That includes your version of MySQL. PS So--where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: This seems likely to be a common error where people want the join on a shared key of some aggregations (each possibly involving joining) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. PS Learn how group by works. Select unaggregated columns only if they are single-valued for group by columns. (Pre-5.7 MySQL lets you break that SQL rule & returns certain random results.) PS "I can't merge" is unclear. So is that whole paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT o.customerId, i.itemCategoryId  SUM(q.quantity) AS total_quantity_ordered
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders_items oi ON oi.orderId=o.orderId
JOIN order_items_quantity q ON oi.orderItemId=q.orderItemId
JOIN items i ON i.itemId=oi.itemId
GROUP BY o.customerId, i.itemCategoryId
```